# Microsoft Test Manager Test Case not using latest associated test method code

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

My server is set up correctly, as far as I can tell. When I select "Run" for a test case in MTM the test reaches out to the controller and executes the associated automation (test method) on the server. So...I updated my Test Method in my Coded UI solution, but when I run the Test Case from Microsoft Test Manager it runs the test method code prior to my updates.

Here's what I've tried:

1. I checked in the changes to my test method into source control.
2. I've unassociated the test method from the test case. Saved. Then once again associated the test case and test method. Still ran the old code when executed from MTM.
3. Restarted the Agent and Controller services
4. Restarted the Server the test is executing on.

What is the deal? Why aren't my checked in updates to my associated test methods not being picked up???

Comment: Did you change the build that's tied to the test plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the build that's tied to the test plan in order for it to pick up the latest changes to your test code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490760(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Creating a new build that grabbed the latest did the trick.